# Payu not returning to website after successful transaction

Tags: asp.net, payu

I have integrated `payu` payment gateway in my ASP.NET application.

Everything is working well, except it is not returning to the website after successful transaction. What could be the issue?

Comment: try to add the code of the  payu

Comment: If "everything is working well except...", obviously, _not_ everything is working well.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue or you forgot to pass the Success URL in payment transaction request. This will return the user to your site after successful transaction.

Make sure to pass these below parameters.

- Success URL
- Failure URL
- Cancel URL